# retry decorator implementation, retries not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-decorators

I have implemented the following retry decorator.

```
def retry(delay=10, retries=4):
    def retry_decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def f_retry(*args, **kwargs):
            while retries > 1:
                try:
                    return f(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as e:
                    msg = "Exception: {}, Retrying in {} seconds...'.format(e, delay)"
                    print(msg)
                    time.sleep(delay)
                    retries -= 1
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

        return f_retry

    return retry_decorator
```

I get the error that retries is not defined. However, retries is mentioned in the function definition. I am unable to figure out what went wrong here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to modify `retries` from within a nested function definition, then you need to declare it `nonlocal`.  You can only do this with Python 3.

Comment: @TomKarzes You should put this as an answer--it's spot on.

Comment: @ManojJadhav nope, `retries` is an argument of the `retry` function, not of `f_retry`.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers yes. you are correct. thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I want it to work with python 2.7 as well

Comment: I am not able to understand that if `delay` variable is known to the inner method, then why not retries?

Comment: If you assign to a variable within a function, Python creates a new local variable in the scope of that function, unless you declare it `global` or `nonlocal`.  If you only read it, then it instead looks for an existing variable in a higher scope.  You would have the same problem with `delay` if you assigned to it.

Comment: It throws an error during `retries > 1` as well, in that case it shouldn't right? Since this is just reading the variable

Comment: If you assign to it anywhere in the function, then it's local everywhere in the function.  It doesn't change from one reference to the next depending on whether the reference includes an assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made it work by collecting the variables retry and delay in a dictionary and then using that inside the function.

```
def retry(delay=10, retries=4):
    def retry_decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def f_retry(*args, **kwargs):
            opt_dict = {'retries': retries, 'delay': delay}
            while opt_dict['retries'] > 1:
                try:
                    return f(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as e:
                    msg = "Exception: {}, Retrying in {} seconds...".format(e, delay)
                    print(msg)
                    time.sleep(opt_dict['delay'])
                    opt_dict['retries'] -= 1
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

        return f_retry

    return retry_decorator
```